# Which alternative jQuery offers similar to List manipulation with javascript?

Tags: jquery

Here is an example of what I need http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html
I need interactive list to which I can add, remove data using javascript without reloading page. Which solutions offer jQuery similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jQuery's [`.live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$("ul").live("click", function(){
  //...
});
```